# Calling two JS functions and syncing them (snakeAnim and Animated Marker)

Tags: javascript, animation, synchronization, leaflet

Currently attempting to track an asset on leaflet. The idea is to draw a polyline, animate it and animate a marker moving along with the polyline. The script for the polyline is the one from IvanSanchez 
[SnakeAnim](https://github.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.Polyline.SnakeAnim)

The script for the animated marker is atogle
[AnimatedMaker](https://github.com/openplans/Leaflet.AnimatedMarker)

Issue is, I believe they're at two different speeds. Any help "merging" the two functions into one? Unfortunately one function uses pixels for distance and the other uses actual physical distance.

Thanks!

```
<div><p> <button id = "start" onclick='snake();'>Start Animation</button></p></div>

var polylines = [];
var markers = [];

for (var i = 0;  i < route.length; i++) {
         polylines.push(L.polyline(route[i]));

            var marker = L.animatedMarker(L.polyline(route[i]).getLatLngs(), {
            icon: Tanker,
            autoStart: false,
            onEnd: function() {
            $(this._shadow).fadeOut();
            $(this._icon).fadeOut(3000, function(){
            map.removeLayer(this);
            });
            }
            });
    }
    var pathmat = L.featureGroup (polylines);

function snake() 
    {               

            pathmat.snakeIn();  
            }
            pathmat.on('snakestart snake snakeend', function(ev){
            console.log(ev.type);
            marker.start();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

it's funny i had the same idea a few month ago.

I'm not using AnimatedMarker but [MovingMarker](https://github.com/ewoken/Leaflet.MovingMarker) because it behaves better when zooming and you can give it a duration array to have a variable speed.

After realizing the same speed issue you talk about, i submitted [an issue](https://github.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.Polyline.SnakeAnim/issues/12) to SnakeAnim project to ask if it was possible to set animation duration instead of animation speed. A dev answered me it was difficult to do. SnakeAnim is not designed that way.

Then i had an idea. It is quite easy to draw a polyline progressively with its `addLatLng` method. All i had to do is fire an event each time the MovingMarker moves, get this event in my code to add current MovingMarker position to the polyline coordinates. [Here](https://eneiluj.gitlab.io/gpxtravelanimdemo/demo1/) is the result.

My modifications to MovingMarker are [here](https://gitlab.com/eneiluj/gpxtravelanim/blob/master/js/MovingMarker.js#L295). Just add this `if` block.
Then i get the `move` event on my MovingMarker this way :

```
var completePolyline = L.polyline(coordinatesTable);
var snakePolyline = L.polyline([]);

// add coordinates to the current snake line when marker moves
function updateSnakeLine(e) {
    var ll = e.target.getLatLng();
    snakePolyline.addLatLng(ll);
}

var marker = L.Marker.movingMarker(completePolyline.getLatLngs(), 20000,{
    autostart: false,
    icon: theicon
});
marker.on('move', updateSnakeLine);
marker.start()
```

One downside of this technique : if the browser is slow during a few milliseconds, it will skip some markers positions so the snakePolyLine might not be strictly equal to the completePolyline. That's why, on animation end, i remove the snakePolyLine and draw the completePolyline.

Comment: So it seems like you are animating your route and marker using just the movingMarker animation, without the use of snakeAnim. Am I right?

Comment: You're right. It is quite difficult to synchronize anything with snakeAnim as its speed is in pixel/sec. So the speed is changing depending on the zoom level. MovingMarker movement management is cleaner, a time is set for the animation so we can say the speed is in "real meters"/sec. Using a MovingMarker as a sort of pen is not so difficult.